# What is the use of <T> expression multiple times?

Tags: java, generics

I have used generics like `<type>` for collections. But why is it used multiple times both in `MyStack<T>` and `StackNode<T>`. As I understand we only need to declare once in `MyStack<T>` and then use only T to reference the `MyStack` class type.

```
public class MyStack<T> {
    private static class StackNode<T> {
        private T data;
        private StackNode<T> next;

        public StackNode(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public T getData() {
            return data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: its java! not C#

Comment: `StackNode` is an inner class (And therefore a separate class)

Comment: so can we use like <T1> instead of <T> as its different class.

Comment: @gisire yes, T1 would be a different type then

Comment: Yes, you could because it's a static class, so its generic type could just as well be named differently. However, for a node to fit to a stack, it's `T1` would need to be the same as the stacks `T`.

Comment: `StackNode` is a different class, but it is related to the outer class by the generic `T`. If you changed it, then it would be generic on a **different** type than the outer class (and I bet your code would not compile); you could have tried it yourself in less time than it took to ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new instance with

```
MyStack<Dog> = new MyStack<Dog>();
```

Then the "data" attribute can store a Dog. All "T" below the first line will use the Dog class in this case.